# Rails Eager Loading on All Finds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

OK, I've been playing around with some of the eager loading things, and have 2 models something like:

```
Class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cookbook
    has_many   :recipetags
end
```

and

```
Class Cookbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipes, :include => [:recipetags]
end
```

Which is working out well, when I find a Cookbook, then I eager load the recipes, and in turn the recipes eager load the :recipetags:

```
cb = Cookbook.find(10590, :include => [:recipes])
```

But what I want to also do is whenever I open a recipe, have it pull in all of it's eager associations automatically - basically I want to do:

```
rec = Recipe.find(123)
```

and have it eager load the :recipetags in that case as well.

I realize this seems trivial, but in actuality I have about 4-5 associations on Recipe, I'm just not showing them here, and rather than having to explicitly do the :include on every find call I'd like it to just happen.  I'm assuming I can override Recipe.find to do it in the Recipe model, but was wondering if there was a cleaner way....

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've been using default_scope to do it on selected models where I always want to eager load:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  default_scope :include => :comments, :order => ["title ASC"]
  ...
end
```

Comment: This looks good - although it looks like it's only available in 2.3+, which introduced some other problems in the app.  I'll see if I can get 2.3.2 working and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with named scopes, but I understand that there were a number of possible bugs with that, hopefully they are all fixed now.