# How do I force active record (Ruby) eager loading at the model level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

We would like to force our Post model to eager load all comments.

Right now we have to specify the eager loading at the find(:all), like below:

```
Post.all(:include => [ :comment ])
```

Is there a way to force an eager loading default at the Post model level, rather than having to do it in every find? Something like below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :include <all comments>  # eager load??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you'll want to [tweak your default_scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042507/rails-eager-loading-on-all-finds) for this.