# Weird empty? behaviour in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Background Information: 
Models: App and Announcement 
Associations: app has_many announcements

Situation:
I have a very simple index action in my AnnouncementsController

```
def index
  app = App.find(params[:app_id])
  @announcements = app.announcements
end
```

I was using the jbuilder gem to output json and it indicated that my @announcements array is empty, but I'm sure I have records in it.  I checked the source and noticed that it used the 'empty?' method to check if the collection is empty before it proceeds. I wanted to see what the 'empty?' method returns so I added a line to the index action:

```
def index
  app = App.find(params[:app_id])
  @announcements = app.announcements
  puts @announcements.empty?.to_s # Returns: "true"
end
```

"True" was not I was expecting because I'm sure I have data. So I added an 'inspect' call to check the contents in the @announcement variable:

```
def index
  app = App.find(params[:app_id])
  @announcements = app.announcements
  puts @announcements.inspect # Returns: "[#<Announcement id: 1, app_id: 1, title: \"20% off everything!\", content: \"Enjoy 20% off everything from now until yesterday!!...\", image: \"0e06b94d-1ac6-4d90-b937-9fa7bfaf90c9.jpg\", status: 0, created_at: \"2012-08-27 15:33:00\", updated_at: \"2012-08-27 15:33:00\">]"
  puts @announcements.empty?.to_s # Returns: "false"
end
```

Hm... interesting. So without changing anything except adding an 'inspect' to my variable, the 'empty?' method returned a different result.

Another interesting observation I made is that if i did this instead:

```
def index
  @announcements = Announcement.all
  puts @announcements.empty?.to_s # Returns: "false"
end
```

The 'empty?' worked fine.

Is anyone else having the same problem, or is it just me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails load collections in a lazy way, so when you inspect it loads it is not empty anymore.

Comment: Hm.. i see... but I don't wanna put a meaningless inspect there, what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Try `@announcements = app.announcements.all`.

Comment: You cab do a include in the find if you just want to change this query or set the default on the model. Check this questions for more info on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042507/rails-eager-loading-on-all-finds