# Rails: Overwrite Devise authentication to 'inner join' a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I think the title is pretty clear.

I'd like to overwrite 'find_for_authentication' function to join a Setting model on user authentication.

My model User has_one Setting

I tried this in my user model, but it doesn't work.

```
def self.find_for_authentication()
    joins(:setting)
    super
end
```

Thank you

Comment: "it doesn't work" means you get an error? What is the error or what do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise has adapters to various different DB types, so this isn't really the layer you want to be doing this on, as it will be further down the method call chain that it actually turns this into any SQL. By the time you get back up to `find_for_authentication` the SQL query has already been executed, so you won't be able to use `.joins` or anything like that.

You could try setting the `default_scope` ([Rails Eager Loading on All Finds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042507/rails-eager-loading-on-all-finds)) for your `User` model, but `default_scope` comes with it's own issues.

Comment: Default_scope is what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
def self.find_for_authentication()
  super.joins(:setting)
end
```

Comment: No it doesn't. 
> undefined method `joins` for #<User:0x00000003cef380>
I think it's because `joins` method is called after `super` get the user